# Rails: Scopes to find records where previous years of the same customer records exist

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I've got a job which belongs to a customer. The jobs regenerate yearly (but sometimes are not accepted). I need scopes on the job to determine the following:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer

  self.new_job # => Customer has no jobs from previous years
    where(customer.jobs.count == 1)  # => Best guess / pseudocode
  end

  self.current # => Customer has a job from the previous year
    where(
      customer.jobs.where("year >= ? and year <= ?", 1.year.ago, 2.years.ago).exists?
    ) # => Best guess / pseudocode
  end

  self.lapsed # => Customer has jobs from previous years, but not last year
    where(
      customer.jobs.not(:current).where(year >= 2.years.ago).exists?
    ) # => Best guess / pseudocode
  end
end
```

I'm trying/hoping that these examples above explain what I'm looking to accomplish.

I've been searching and thinking about this for a while but I'm still not able to put together how I'd accomplish this. Basically scopes that will let me query jobs based on if they have previous years' jobs from the same customer that exist or not.

Should I add/do I need a has_many / belongs_to relationship for previous years/future years on the jobs model? I keep thinking that wouldn't be necessary to add another database column since I can just query on the customer's jobs instead?

Then I could do something like this to accomplish the exists (?):

```
 includes(:previous_jobs).where(# more constraints).where.not(previous_jobs): { id: nil })
```

Could I make a previous jobs belongs_to/has_many (self-referential?) based off of the customer ID, or would I need to add foreign key and write a script to assign previous/next job id's to existing records?

Comment: Overwriting the `.new` method with a scope like that is a really bad idea. `.new` in Ruby should always be a factory method that returns a new instance. Anything else is a really bad violation of the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Oooh! Good point @max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your approach is dead wrong - scoping `Customer` should not be in the `Job` class.

What you can do instead is create scoped associations:

```
class Customer
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :current_jobs, class_name: 'Job', 
    -> { where(created_at: 1.year.ago..Time.now) }
  has_many :lapsed_jobs, class_name: 'Job', 
    -> { where('created_at >= ?', 1.year.ago) }
end

class Job
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

These all reference the same `jobs.customer_id` column so no changes to the schema are needed.

By using a `LEFT INNER JOIN` you can limit the `Customer` records retrieved without counting since only rows which have at least one match in the joined table are returned:

```
Customer.joins(:jobs) # only customers with jobs
Customer.joins(:current_jobs) # has a job which is not older than a year
Customer.joins(:lapsed_jobs) # has a job older than one year
```

To get jobs where the customer has not created a job in the last year you would do it by a subquery:

```
Job.where.not(customer: Customer.joins(:current_jobs))
```

Comment: I was thinking this, but the use case is: "Give me all jobs that don't have jobs from the same customer in the previous year"

Comment: That use case does not even make sense with your model - a job does not have a job - customers do.

Comment: Exactly. Thats my question. How can I set up a self referential association, where a job DOES have other jobs based on having the same customer_id.

Comment: You're overthinking it. `Job.where.not(customer: Customer.joins(:current_jobs))` should give you the desired result.

Comment: To phrase this more correctly - Give me all the jobs where the customer has not made an order in the last year.

Comment: Thanks max, I think that should do it! Wanna post that up there in the answer? Gonna accept it.